# What if a file is changed at the same time rsync is copying it to destination?

Tags: rsync

Would the file just be corrupted at destination or rsync will do something like check hashes again to make an exact copy that match the source?

Answer (score 1):

When rsync is started it builds up a file list and then starts to copy those files. This file list is not being updated during the run. The actual data is then copied.
There's a chance that rsync might actually corrupt your file. When rsync starts to read a file and an application is writing that file at the same time, you might end up with a corruped file.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Just one more question: Is there a tool that can "mirror" a file the same way database replication works?